# SQL Server 2017 on RHEL Linux with IDM for AD authentication

Tags: linux, sql-server-2017, redhat, windows-authentication

We are using Red Hat IDM to authenticate AD users to SQL Server. Users can login successfully to SQL Server with SSMS and SQL CMD with AD Authentication. But running some elevated commands from SSMS or SQL CMD can run only once in session and it kick out AD authenticated users from SQL Server with the following error:

Error 15404 ‘Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user '%ls', error code 0x80090304'

Comment: There's a lot of reasons to stay away from SQL on Linux. All of them are valid, and probably you should follow best practices here which is: Microsoft is working only in Microsoft environment and mostly with default settings. From my experience follows that important changes in configurations are simply not documented, do not works and usually you have insecure unmanageable nightmare

Answer (score 0):

I had similar experience. I believe this was due to a limitation in IDM. There is currently a bugzilla filed for this issue. I believe Red Hat is working on addressing this issue.